# xText 2 - Processing tokens

Tags: java, xtext

Is it possible to modify a token before it gets assigned to an EAttribute or
to assign the same token to multiple EAttributes?

Something like the following (Pseudocode):

```
MyRuleWithModifiedToken:
    'entity' name=${ID + 'Entity'} '{' ... '}'

MyRuleUsingSameToken:
    name=ID sameName=${<ID}
```

I read about using a [PostProcessor written in xTend](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.xtext.doc/help/metamodelInference.html) but it's not allowed not modify the data of the generated model.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the Token through using a IValueConverter - this works on Terminal or on Datatype rule so you may have to introduce one for the special EAttribute you want to do the special conversion.

```
EntityName: ID 'Entity';
MyRuleWithModifiedToken: 'entity' name=EntityName ....;
```

the ValueConverter then would remove the Entity postfix when doing the tovalue conversion and adding it when doing the toString conversion.